# VueJS 1: Trying to pass data from one component to another on button click

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Component WarehouseAdd

```
<el-col :span="4" v-if="isWarehouseReplicate" class="apply">
    <button class="btn blue" :disabled = "isApply" @click="onClickApply()"> Apply
        <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
    </button>
</el-col>
<tableview isVisible="isVisibleTableView"></tableview>

<script>
import tableview from './TableView'
components: {
  tableview
},
data() {
  return {
    isVisibleTableView: false,
  }
},
onClickApply: function () {
  console.log('onclick');
  this.isVisibleTableView = true;
}
}
```

component Tableview

```
<template>
  <div class="row" v-if="isVisible">
   // some code
</template>

<script> 
  props: [
   'isVisible']
</script>
```

Initially isVisibleTableView should be false and on buttton click i want to update the value to true.
Here I am trying to show tableview component on Button click but this is not working in my case.
I am trying to change the prop in run time.
What can I possibly use in order to accomplish ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your method `onClickApply` from the parent inside the `methods` object.

Otherwise, Here, you missed the `:` here `isVisible="isVisibleTableView"` so the props was not reactive.

---

Example :

here the parent has a `isVisibleTableView` property passed to the child through the `show` props

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child',
  props: ['show'],
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    isVisibleTableView: false
  }),
  
  methods: {
    toggleShow(){
      this.isVisibleTableView = !this.isVisibleTableView
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>this is the parent</p>
  <button @click="toggleShow">{{isVisibleTableView ? "Hide child" : "Show child"}}</button>
  <child :show="isVisibleTableView"></child>
</div>

<template id="child">
  <h2 v-if="show">This is the child</h2>    
</template>
```

Comment: Hi @RenaudC5 I tried doing the changes but it still doesn't work in my case. The TableView component is unable to take the value when I update it in run time (after clicking the button)

Comment: Have you try putting the function inside the `methods` ? If you can please provide a codesandbox, it would be easier to help

Comment: Yes the functions are inside the methods. Just that I did not mention it in the code. Haven't actually used codesandbox will check how it works

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change this:

```
<tableview isVisible="isVisibleTableView"></tableview>
```

To This:

```
<tableview :isVisible="isVisibleTableView"></tableview>
```

Answer (score 0):

isVisible="!isVisibleTableView"

Sometimes it is necessary to work with negations in templates. See if that works. Hugs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).